# Installing Bioconductor highthroughputassays workflow gives rgl errors and fail to load

Tags: r, runtime-error, bioconductor

When I try to install the bioconductor workflow 'highthroughputassays' as follows (and as [described here](https://www.bioconductor.org/help/workflows/highthroughputassays/#flow-cytometry)):

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/workflows.R")
> workflowInstall("highthroughputassays")
```

It installs a lot of dependent packages, but just before ending the installation it gives the following errors:

```
No man pages found in package  ‘highthroughputassays’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
dlopen(/Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
Reason: image not found
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/highthroughputassays’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘highthroughputassays’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/hb/sc3x6vtj0ys009qnyplbp2_h1g5hgm/T/RtmpDkWkRH/downloaded_packages’
```

Because of those errors, the workflow does not load;

```
library(flowStats)
```

gives a similar error after installing packages as described above.

I have tried it on 3 different Mac computers (all with the newest OS X, but one of them had the 3.3.1 version of R (The newest version is 3.3.2))

When trying `library(rgl)` I get the following error:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
dlopen(/Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/johansenkh/Library/R/3.3/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rgl’
```

Comment: Does this give error? `library(rgl)`

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, See updated question for error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

The problem was with loading 'rgl'.

By installing XQUARTZ ([www.XQUARTZ.com](http://www.xQUARTZ.com)) followed by restarting OS X (Log out and log in) the rgl-package worked. Thereafter the workflow installed as indicated above.